# Where should I put the C source files in a Python program?

Tags: python

I am trying to compile a Python program which includes some C files.

In one file `emodule.c` it reads:

```
#include "Python.h"
#include "ul/ul.h"
```

I already have the `ul` folder and put it in the same folder with `emodule.c`, however, when I run `python setup.py build`, it stills says:

```
fatal error: ul/ul.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Where should I put the `ul` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `include_dirs = ['ul']` to the call to `setup()` in `setup.py`.

See the [Preprocessor Options](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#preprocessor-options) section of the `setupscripts` documentation for more information.